# How to create single page app and have fixed partitions transition into eachother

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a basic web app that I would like to have a set of 5 views.

It is single page application where page one is a load screen / login. I want the user to only see this page. When the user clicks submit it will transition to the the next page, and only see that page.

I have two issues:

1. Everything that I want visible on the first page does not fit the screen.
2. I can scale the sizes (heights/widths) of buttons and imgs but this would only be subject to one type of phone. I am using bootstrap 3 to fix this.

What is the best way to structure this simple app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use bootstrap to fix your view sizes, and AngularJS with UI.router using states for your application. They have good documentation at their [site](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router). 
It sounds like you could also possibly use [nested states](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views)